# Reading an object from another class

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am using XCode 4.0.2 for a iOS4 project.

When my app starts, the application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in the application delegate loads a NSDictionary form a plist:

```
NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"RGBSpaces" ofType:@"plist"];
RGBSpacesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

The NSDictionary is readonly. How can I read one or more elements of NSDictionary from an arbitrary class?

Thank you

Comment: If this is data used internally by the app itself, you might consider putting it in NSUserDefaults. That will make it universally accessible.

Comment: I don't recommend placing data in the AppDelegate. If you want to make that global data, consider creating a singleton class for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIApplication *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

And then you can use appDelegate to access its properties including dictionaries.

Comment: I don't recommend this. This will require a terrible upcast and if you do it once, you'll do it more and more and your code will become really bad with all that.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then doing with Appdelegate the simpler option would be create a class for that of type NSObject and you update and get value just by importing that class wherever required.Another option would be NSUserDefaults.Depends on the requirements which to use.